# I have a dateTime as an index in a dataframe and I want to use just the hour as the xtick label

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I have some time series data in a line plot and I want to edit the xticks so they either display the full date or at the very least the hour for each data point. The data is indexed by a dateTime column like this:

```
                           Hourly_diff
dateTimeUtc                           
2022-09-01 00:00:00+00:00         18.0
2022-09-01 01:00:00+00:00        -20.0
2022-09-01 02:00:00+00:00         56.0
                               ...
2022-10-01 17:00:00+00:00         69.0
2022-10-01 18:00:00+00:00       -465.0
2022-10-01 19:00:00+00:00       -617.0
2022-10-01 20:00:00+00:00        173.0
2022-10-01 21:00:00+00:00        378.0
```

Which I then plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
fig.suptitle('Error 1')
ax.set_xlabel('Hour')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
ax.set_ylabel('Error', rotation = 0)
ax.grid(alpha=0.25)
legs = day_1.columns[:]
ax.set_xticks(day_1.index)

for column in day_1:
    ax.plot(day_1.index, day_1[column])
    ax.legend(legs,loc = 'upper right')  
    
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But, I only get the first 4 characters of the index. I would like the full date to be shown. Or...

Is it somehow possible to plot just the hour as an xtick label without typing them all out and get rid of the rest of the date?

I tried extracting the hours and then calling it in the set_xtick argument like so.

```
hours = data_index.hour
ax.set_xtick(hours)
```

but although the plot appears, the x axis is completely blank and I don't get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating my own range of times and plotting the error against that, as follows.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
fig.suptitle('Error')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
ax.set_ylabel('Error', rotation = 0)
ax.grid(alpha=0.25)
legs = day_1.columns[:]
times = pd.date_range("00:00", "23:00", freq="60min").strftime('%H:%M')
#ax.set_xticklabels(day_1.index.hour)
for column in day_1:
    ax.plot(times, day_1[column])
    ax.set_xticks(hours)
    ax.legend(legs,loc = 'upper right')  
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using datetime as the independent variable (x axis), you could use the plot_date function instead, like this:

```
import numpy as np

hours = data_index.hour # your hours vector
data = np.random.rand(24) # replace with your data

plt.plot_date(hours, data, fmt='H') #H to display hours
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),
         'rotation', 90)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem with this approach, I've found, is that the hours vector is just a list of numbers from zero through to 24 so when I plot it with the plot_date, python parses it as the Unix epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970) and the xticks are thus labelled consecutively from this date.

Comment: Could you just replace the hours variable (hours = data_index.hour) with the variable that is actually of a datetime type (dateTimeUtc)?

Comment: It just gave me the same result as before